# Can`t merge Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have around 8 .csv files in a given directory. When I am running this code, getting empty dataframe  (new_df which I have specified.).

I have already seen how to use concat function to get the job done but just wondering what i am doing wrong in my approach since i read documentation on DataFrame.append() and it should have worked.

```
path = Path("/content/Sales_data/")
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in path.glob("*.csv"):
  df = pd.read_csv(file)
  new_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

new_df
```

Appreciate any recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `new_df` to the DataFrame with appended data:

```
new_df = new_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

The problem with your code is due to the fact that `append` returns a new object, it does not modify the existing DataFrame in place

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue)